# Reduce the query time in solr

Tags: search, solr, indexing

I am using solr for searching. My index size is getting larger hour by hour. So the query time is also getting higher. Many people suggested for sharding. Is this the last option. What should I do now?

Comment: In order to help you it would be cool to (1) know your schema (2) see the queries which are slow. Probably these are points where you can fine tune.

Comment: try out caching as per your data

Answer (score 0):

- before rushing into sharding, which will definetly make your search faster, you might have a look at your schema, and see if you can do any optimisations there.
- Use Stop words: stop words are very common words that might inflate the index size un-necessarily. Try to use stop words whenever you need them.
- Avoid Synonyms with 'Expand' option if you can. Those also expand the index enormously.
- Avoid using N-Grams with large range. This will generate too many combinations if you have large size.
- Use query filters (fq parameter) when you just need a filter. Filter queries are faster than normal queries, and they don't apply any scoring. It is just a filter. So if you need to AND queries together, put the filter queries in the fq parameter.
- Run "Optimise Index" from time to time to get rid of deleted docs in the index, and to reduce index size.
- use debugQuery=on and see if you can spot any thing that is taking long time.
- try to use documentCache if you have large document size
- try to use filterCache if you have repeated filter queries
- try to use queryResultCache if you have repeated queries.

If non of the above resulted in any performance gains, then you might consider sharding/distributed search